# import arcpy function - model builder

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, toolbox

I'm trying to execute a model made in ArcGIS outside ESRI environment. 
I want to import several CSV files to my database

This is my code to import my toolbox/model  where:

```
IJA0101X00006666importcsv: model name
test: toolbox name
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:/projet/"
arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"c:/projet/test.tbx")
arcpy.IJA0101X00006666importcsv_test
print "Script finished"
```

In MS DOS I have a message that the script has finished, but when I see the database nothing has changed. Apparently the model didn’t import any data….

Can anyone tell me where the error is?

Comment: does your code produce any errors? try adding a print statement after each line and see where it hangs

Comment: No error produced
I don’t have many knowledge on python that’s why I made all the operations in model builder in ArcGIS
Export to Phyton code didn’t work neither because of the errors I don’t know how to solve. I thought this would be the easiest way  
I just want to launch a model made by me outside ArcGIS environment in order to schedule the operation in windows

Comment: you can successfully import arcpy outside the ArcGIS environment so your using the same machine that has ArcGIS installed but just running the IDLE terminal?

Comment: Booth model/ArcGIS/Data are in same machine
In aArcGIS environment I have zero problems, launching the model in python calling //import arcpy
I have no problem neither
It’s when I go to see the data that the model is supposed to treat that nothing happened

Comment: what toolbox are you using? its a custom tool? post the code

Comment: Yes it’s a custom toolbox. All the geoprocessing tools used are from ESRI, no outside sources.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing "Script finished" because it says to print it. There is no try or catch in what you added in for the code. Or any procedures that make sense. The line "arcpy.IJA0101X00006666importcsv_test" would not execute, because it's not valid.

You want to run the model as a python script, only what you shared isn't the model. It appears that what you've copied looks like the results of the model running in the results panel for geoprocessing in ArcMap.

To obtain the python script of the model. 
1. Open model in model viewer
2. Go to menu item model
3. Click export, and then export as python script. 
4. Save script to a location that you can easily access via command prompt.

(When trying to run this python script, I highly suggest that you write a .bat file and use logging.)

After these steps then you'll have the python script. Keep in mind that doesn't mean that your machine will automatically recognize python functions. You may still need to add an environmental variable to the python.exe.

But first thing first, export the model to python script.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved
The error was in « intermediate data » in the model
Model export to .py and works marvelous outside ArcGIS environment
Thank a lot for yours answers you are awesome!!!